# Is there anyway to change the focal length of the navigation camera?

Tags: camera, navigation

Is there anyway to change the focal length of the navigation camera? When I do an archviz walkthrough, the view feels tighter than it should and I would like to adjust the focal length when doing a walkthrough with the navigation camera.

Comment: N panel > View > View > Focal Lenght?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. <kbd>N</kbd> *Properties Panel > View tab > View > Focal Length*. For more context and information, see the Blender Manual page [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/sidebar.html#view).